# Can files be uploaded to a compute engine on GCP using an application page written in php/html?

Tags: php, mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Can we upload image files to a GCP running compute engine directly using PHP?

I know that it can be done using the backend ssh on GCP.

I have a solution that works in my local system to upload files but does not work on GCP.

Based on initial research it appears that GCP does not allow file upload directly.

Need confirmation though or if there is a way in which file upload can work, please enlighten.

Comment: @ John by php frontend I meant an application page designed in php/html for uploading files to a folder in gcp compute engine. I have php code running on lamp in the compute engine

Comment: @ John unfortunately they are not working, I have a working piece of code which works okay in my local system but fails to upload files in gcp running a lamp on compute engine. you might want to try yourself on gcp using php.

Comment: by try yourself I meant try it on gcp running a compute engine which runs lamp

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it can be done directly through php, through ssh yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload files with PHP.

If you want to upload to the server local disk, things become a bit simpler. Just ensure you have PHP configured for upload: [PHP File Upload](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

If you want to upload to Google Storage, say to a bucket, you'd need to authenticate and get access there. Google Cloud SDK can provide this. Then you can install API Client Libraries for PHP and optional Cloud SDK components. That way you might call `gcloud` shell command or use  API. Cloud SDK will provide transparent connection and authentication for you so that you can upload to the Google Storage.

Please see:

[Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/)

[Google API Client Libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/)

Comment: I could not find any documentation in the links shared which mentions about file upload using a php/html application. kindly enlighten.

Comment: @Blank, could this example from the links shared above work for you: [large-file-upload.php](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/large-file-upload.php) ?

Comment: @ mebius99 I think the link you shared has code to upload files to a g-drive using php. i am trying to upload files to a folder inside a google compute engine running lamp using a php/html application.

Comment: Broadened the answer

Comment: File uploads are on in the php.ini file